# Print PDF using puppeteer in Windows

Tags: java, node.js, printing, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I have an HTML file that loaded in puppeteer and convert it to pdf.
I want to print the pdf file. Right now I use nodejs to print the
generated pdf file. The printing is done correctly when the width is
smaller that the height. But when the width is greater than height
then the printer prints the file with wrong dimensions and wrong
orientation.

This is my nodejs code that generate and print
pdf file.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const expressWs = require('express-ws');
const printer = require('pdf-to-printer');

let browser;

async function initializeBrowser() {
    if (!browser) {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: 'new',//'new'
        });
    }
}

async function printHtmlToCustomSize(page, htmlFilePath, outputPath, widthMM, heightMM, printerName) {
    await page.setViewport({
        width:  widthMM* 25.4,
        height: heightMM * 25.4,
        deviceScaleFactor: 2,
    });

    const fileUrl = `file://${path.resolve(htmlFilePath)}`;
    console.log(fileUrl);

    await page.goto(fileUrl);



    await page.pdf({
        path: outputPath,
        width: `${widthMM}mm`,
        height: `${heightMM}mm`,
    });

    const printerOptions = {
        printer: printerName,
    };

    await printer.print(outputPath, printerOptions);
    console.log(`PDF printed to ${printerName}`);
}

async function startServer() {
    const app = express();
    expressWs(app);

    app.ws('/print', (ws, req) => {
        ws.on('message', async (message) => {
            const { htmlFilePath, outputPath, widthMM, heightMM, printerName } = JSON.  parse(message);

            await initializeBrowser();
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            try {
                await printHtmlToCustomSize(page, htmlFilePath, outputPath, widthMM, heightMM, printerName);
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
            } finally {
                await page.close();
            }
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('WebSocket server listening on port 3000');
    });
}

startServer();
```

Also I use [this](https://www.winprt.com/wp300b-4-inch-label-printer-product/) thermal printer.

[This is the printed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd5fG.jpg).

[This must be the printed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykIHT.png).
Also this is my html label code:

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            @media    print {
                body {
                    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                }
                hr{
                    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                }
                body{
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                .preview-mode{
                    border: 0 !important;
                }
            }
            body{
                line-height: 1.5;
            }
            .preview-body {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
/*                font-size: 14px;*/
                font-family: Arial;
            }
            .table{
                font-size:inherit;
            }
            @page{
                margin: 0;
            }
            hr{
                margin: 0;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
            }
            .preview-border{
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                /*width: 100%;
                height: 100%;*/
            }

            .preview-mode .textarea,
            .preview-mode input {
                border: 0;
                resize: none;
                user-select: none;
                writing-mode: unset;
                cursor: default;
                outline: none;
                pointer-events: none;
                touch-action: none;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            .preview-mode table {
                resize: none;
                user-select: none;
                writing-mode: unset;
                outline: none;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            .preview-mode .draggable-table td .textarea {
                resize: none;
                user-select: none;
                writing-mode: unset;
                outline: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .preview-mode .draggable-table td{
                position: relative;
            }

            .preview-mode .draggable-table .element{
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .preview-mode .element {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: default;
                resize: none;
            }

            .preview-mode .delete-element,
            .preview-mode .duplicate-element,
            .preview-mode .rotate-element {
                display: none;
            }
            .preview-mode .textarea span {
                display: block !important;
                font-size: inherit;
            }

            .table-inside-border td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .table-inside-border tr:first-child td {
                border-top: 0;
            }

            .table-inside-border tr:last-child td {
                border-bottom: 0;
            }

            .table-inside-border tr td:first-child,
            .table-inside-border tr th:first-child {
                border-left: 0;
            }

            .table-inside-border tr td:last-child,
            .table-inside-border tr th:last-child {
                border-right: 0;
            }

            .table-full-border,
            .table-full-border tr,
            .table-full-border td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .table-outside-border {
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-outside-border tr:first-child {
                border-top: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-outside-border tr+tr {
                border-top: 0;
            }

            .table-outside-border td {
                border: 0;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-outside-border td+td {
                border-left: 0;
            }

            .table-top-border tr:first-child {
                border-top: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-top-border tr,
            .table-top-border td {
                border: 0;
            }

            .table-bottom-border tr:last-child {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-bottom-border tr,
            .table-bottom-border td {
                border: 0;
            }

            .table-left-border tr td:first-child {
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-left-border tr,
            .table-left-border td {
                border: 0;
            }

            .table-right-border tr td:last-child {
                border-right: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .table-right-border tr,
            .table-right-border td {
                border: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <input name="label_identifier" type="hidden" value="LB-65c49a6277c7f8.20063631">
        <input name="width" type="hidden" value="264.566929137">
        <input name="height" type="hidden" value="207.8740157505">

        <div class="print-wrapper">
            <table class="table table-bordered m-auto central-table preview-mode" style="position:relative;height:207.8740157505px; width: 264.566929137px">
                <tbody>
                                            <tr class="central-table-row">
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                <div class="draggable element draggable-text ui-draggable" id="droppable-1707383401662" data-id="text" style="z-index:1; top:-0.5px;left:-0.5px;" data-format-selected="1"><div class="element-child"><div contenteditable="true" class="textarea ui-resizable"><span>Text 1</span><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div></div></div></td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                <div class="draggable element draggable-text ui-draggable" id="droppable-1707383410831" data-id="text" style="z-index: 1; top: 2.5px; left: 222.281px;" data-format-selected="1"><div class="element-child"><div contenteditable="true" class="textarea ui-resizable"><span>Text 2</span><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div></div></div></td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            <tr class="central-table-row">
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                <div class="draggable element draggable-text ui-draggable" id="droppable-1707383429730" data-id="text" style="z-index: 1; top: 182.453px; left: 226.172px;" data-format-selected="1"><div class="element-child"><div contenteditable="true" class="textarea ui-resizable"><span>Text4</span><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div></div></div></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            <tr class="central-table-row">
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                <div class="draggable element draggable-text ui-draggable" id="droppable-1707383427788" data-id="text" style="z-index: 1; top: 182.906px; left: 2px;" data-format-selected="1"><div class="element-child"><div contenteditable="true" class="textarea ui-resizable"><span>Text3</span><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div></div></div></td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                            <td class="droppable ui-droppable">
                                </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(document.getElementsByClassName('central-table')[0].classList.contains('preview-mode')){
                document.getElementsByClassName('central-table')[0].classList.add('preview-border');
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute( 'class', 'preview-body');
                document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute( 'class', 'preview-body');
                var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('ui-rotatable-handle');
                while(elements.length > 0){
                    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Also the nodejs must be run with websockets and the body of request must be like this:

```
{
"htmlFilePath":"page.html",
"outputPath":"./output.pdf",
"widthMM":70,
"heightMM":55,
"printerName":"printerName"
}
```

Comment: @KJ it is possible to define custom paper size to my printer using a programming lang without using TSPL EPL ZPL or DPL?

Comment: @KJ I use pdf-to-printer in order to send to specific printer the pdf. Also my PDF has size 70mm 60mm. For labels with smaller or equal width and height the print it's ok but for labels with width greater than height the problem is the orientation and the size of page where white space added around  the pdf content.

Comment: @KJ I tried with sumatra but nothing changed. Something else to suggest me ??